# No funciona pagina de error 404 en Angular 8 con path: '**'

Tags: angular, routes, routing, 404

Tengo el codigo en mi `app.routing.module.ts`
donde esta configurado para que si algun link no existe, vaya al componente  `DefaultPageComponent`
El problema es que al agregar el path *{path: '**', redirectTo: '404'}* me esta llevando a la pagina `DefaultPageComponent`   **en todos los links, incluso los que si existen**, y no entiendo porque esta pasando.
Uno de los link al cual deberia acceder correctamente: http://localhost:4200/suip-backoffice/#/causistica/list

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { DefaultPageComponent } from './default-page/default-page.component';
import { LoginDummyComponent } from './login-dummy/login-dummy.component';

const routes: Routes = [

 {
   path: '',
   redirectTo: 'dashboard',
   pathMatch: 'full'

 },

 {
   path: 'dashboard',
   component: LoginDummyComponent

 },


 {
   path: '404',
   component: DefaultPageComponent
 },

 {
   path: '**', 
   redirectTo: '404'
 }


];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
 constructor(private router: Router) {
   this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
     return false;
   }
   this.router.events.subscribe((evt: any) => {
     if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       // trick the Router into believing it's last link wasn't previously loaded
       this.router.navigated = false;
       // if you need to scroll back to top, here is the right place
       window.scrollTo(0, 0);
     }
   });
 }
}
```

**defaul-page.component.ts**

````
@Component({
 selector: 'app-default-page',
 templateUrl: './default-page.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./default-page.component.css']
})
export class DefaultPageComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

} ```
````

Comment: Probablemente sea por el orden en el que importas los módulos en el `AppModule`. Asegúrate de que el `AppRoutingModule`, sea el último (o al menos el último que añada rutas) en el array de `imports:[]` del `AppModule`.

Comment: Es correcto! Funciono perfectamente con tu solucion! mil gracias!

Comment: @Gonzalo por favor da por cerrada la pregunta si no muchos podemos ver la pregunta  y trataremos de responderte

Comment: > No entiendo porque cuando el que publica una pregunta y encuentra una
> respuesta como se da en la cadena de comentarios de esta no la
> cierra? y asi se evita que muchos al verla tratemos de responderla

Comment: @nestdan cómo cierro la pregunta? Perdón, nunca me pasó.

Comment: Gonzalo podes decirle a @akotech si a el le interesa publicar la solución que te dio y si no le interesa vos mismo podes publicar la respuesta referenciándolo .Disculpame es que me puse a tratar de solucionar tu problema y cuando veo los comentarios ya estaba solucionado el problema  saludos

Comment: Hola Nestdan! ahi publique la solucion y le hice clic al tilde (que quedo en color verde), como lo referencio a el y como finalizo todo? gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue el orden en el que importa los módulos en el AppModule. Me asegure que el AppRoutingModule, sea el último (o al menos el último que añada rutas) en el array de imports:[] del AppModule.

Answer (score 0):

La redirección ocupa llevar la `/` al principio:

```
...
{
   path: '',
   redirectTo: '/dashboard',
   pathMatch: 'full'

 },
```

Lo mismo con el 404.

```
...
 {
   path: '**', 
   redirectTo: '/404',
   pathMatch: 'full'
 }
```

Comment: Me sigue pasando lo mismo @Legna, es muy raro. Todos los links se redirigen hacia la 404

Answer (score 0):

Pueden ocurrir varias cosas.
La que me imagino en principio es que en el AppComponent.html estás llamando al DefaultComponent entonces a cada página que vayas, se mostrará.
O incluso en el LoginDummyComponent.

Otra opcion que podrías probar: es agregar el `pathMatch: 'full'`.